# Windows 10: how to prevent File Explorer from opening .IMG files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-extension, img

Dear fellow Windows warriors,

I've stumbled across an interesting problem.
A user in fairly pristine Windows 10 has received a suspicious file by e-mail, and due to momentary lack of concentration, managed to save it on the desktop and double-click it.
The file was called "something.jpg (1).img" and the user even has file extensions set to "display" systemwide - just didn't pay attention.

When I was called to assist, the file was on the desktop and could not be deleted, "the file is open by another program". The open handle could not be found by file name via Process Explorer or Handles (tool by SysInternals) - possibly some masking done by the malware (rootkit style?). A reboot into safe mode did get rid of the hidden process, and I could delete the file.
I did restore the OS from a backup afterwards, just in case...

Before I restored the OS from backup, I tried to check what "default app" is assigned by extension to .IMG. Curiously to me, there was none! The extension .img was not in the system-wide list... Yet, when I created an empty file, and renamed to test.img, the File Explorer (Windows default shell) did try to open the file, did not report "no default app, pick one", instead complained about the file contents being unexpected/malformed...

I.e., this appears to be some internal function of the File Explorer in Windows 10, which can be exploited by a properly crafted file! Yuck.

Is there some way to plug this silly hole? (Yeah right - ban that extension in the mail server. Already done.)

Perhaps I should define an explicit file association, either to a safe app that knows what to do with some legit .img files (Rufus?), or to an app that will rightfully refuse to have anything to do with an .IMG file of any kind... (e.g., calc.exe) and hope that my bogus / tongue-in-cheek association won't get overriden or reset, sooner or later...

Comment: It probably wasn’t actually an image file. It likely had two file extensions.

Comment: Exactly right. And it is the last extension that matters, on a filename, in Windows. And, Explorer has some compile-time built-in association for that particular extension. And, the Explorer's internal processing based on the .IMG extension lends itself to "remote execution" attacks.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? File Explorer viewing the file isn't the reason the malicious file was ran, it was the fact, the file was executed by the user. The reason the file was not prevent from being executed likely has to do with the size of the file, likely filled with 0's, making it appear the file was much larger than it was.

Comment: You don't say how you checked the "Default app". Have you looked in the fegistry under `HKCR:\.img`? If it has a string value for `(Default)`, look for that next. Also check under `HKCR\SystemFileAsociations\.img` and `HKCU\ software/Microsoft/ Windows/ CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img\UserChoice`.

Comment: @KeithMiller that was spot on, got me started. If you turn this into an anwer, I will flag it as the accepted answer. I also have something to add on top - wondering if I should add my own answer, or possibly edit the question (append my further steps) - not sure what would be proper behavior on my part. Hints welcome.

Comment: I'll post an answer. Not sure about your addition without knowing more. If it's too complex for a comment, start by appending to your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how you checked the "Default app". There are several locations to check in the fegistry:

1. `HKCR:\.img`

   - If it has a string value for (Default), that is the [*ProgID*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-file-types):

   > File name extension subkeys have the following general form: extension=ProgID. File name extension subkeys are stored in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT subtree.

   If the key has a `PerceivedType` value, take note of that as well.
2. Next, check under:

   - `HKCR\<*ProgID*>\Shell\Open`
     This may be the program that is opening your file, or it may be over-ridden by other keys.
3. Next, check both:

   - `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.img\Shell\Open`
   - `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\<PerceivedType>\Shell\Open`

     Verbs other than `Open` defined under this key appear in the context menu regardless of `<ProgID>` or `UserChoice` (see below) associations.
4. Finally, check under:

   - `HKCU\Ssoftware\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img\UserChoice`
     This is the "most likely suspect" as it is set by the "What program do you want to use to open this file?" dialog and will override any `Open` verbs defined under `HKCR`. Deleting this key will return the filetype to the defaults found under `HKCR` or, if none are defined under `HKCR`, the type will return to its unassociated state (what you want!) and double-clicking a file of that type in **Explorer** will display the "This file has no program associated with it" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has double-clicked the file, it was him that executed it,
not Explorer and not a bug (at least not a bug in Explorer).

The user has with a total lack of attention ignored the
warning message by Windows for downloaded files, and elected
to open the file, thereby infecting his own computer.

There are several known bugs in Windows as regarding the opening of
specially-crafted image files. You should update fully Windows,
although I can't promise that there don't exist more bugs like that
which are currently unknown but exploited.

User education and vigilance is the only solution.

Comment: Being a bit of a system tinkerer, I disagree. The shell should only open files (especially, execute them) for which it thinks it knows the file type. In windows, executable file types are recognized by filename extension, only then by the file format (DOS MZ, Windows PE-COFF etc). In UNIX/Linux, the extension has not much of a meaning, and there are other mechanisms of recognizing the executable file type by contents = binary image formats supported + the #! script interpreter notation. Yes the user did goof up, but the implicit association built in Explorer did not help prevent the attack.

Comment: In Windows the extension is everything and determines the program that will handle the file. You can perhaps blame the antivirus for not detecting the infected file (and get a better one), but you can't blame Windows for doing what it's designed to do by its philosophy and structure.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone who responded.
Special thanks to Keith Miller, who has provided the right clues, for me to re-catch traction.

First, how I originally checked the associated app by extension: I went via the Windows 10 GUI for configuring "Default apps". The .img extension was not in its list. However, regarding my early conclusion that the File Explorer uses an internal / compile-time association: I was wrong about that.

Following Keith's advice, I've checked the places in the Registry, where the filename extensions can be "registered":

1.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.img]
@="Windows.IsoFile"
```

pointing to:

2.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Windows.IsoFile\shell\mount]
"ExplorerCommandHandler"="{9ab3b1c9-3225-4bb4-93b6-bfb3c0d93743}"
```

and further to

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{9ab3b1c9-3225-4bb4-93b6-bfb3c0d93743}]
@="Disc Image Mount"
```

So that registration does exist, and is telling me, that the .IMG file is considered a mountable image of a filesystem.

3.

```
HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.img   <-- doesn't exist
```

and

4.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img\OpenWithList]
"a"="{F38BF404-1D43-42F2-9305-67DE0B28FC23}\\Explorer.exe"
"MRUList"="a"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img\OpenWithProgids]
"Windows.IsoFile"=hex(0):
```

So that registration does exist, too.

I went on to erase the first registration, and that did not change the behavior of Windows. When I double-clicked an empty file called test.img, the Explorer still tried to open it as a FS image.
After I erased the second registration (registry branch under HKCU \ ... \ FileExts), Windows finally started to treat the extension as unknown.

=> the association of .IMG is not compiled in, in the File Explorer, after all :-)

Next, I tried associating a different app to the .IMG extension.
I chose IrfanView, as I was missing it on that computer anyway, and it hooks the .IMG extension by default. I asked irfanview during installation to hook all image types.

Interestingly to me, after the installation wizard finished, Windows would *not* open .IMG, nor .JPG / .PNG / .GIF, in IrfanView. So I went again into the Windows Default Apps GUI, found those classic picture extensions mapped to "photoes" or something... I don't recall what the IMG was mapped to. I just clicked them all to Irfanview in that Default Apps GUI, and this time my selection sunk in.

This is how .IMG ended up in my Registry:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.img]
@="img_auto_file"
```

and

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img\OpenWithList]
"a"="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\\OpenWith.exe"
"b"="i_view64.exe"
"MRUList"="ba"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img\OpenWithProgids]
"img_auto_file"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.img\UserChoice]
"ProgId"="Applications\\i_view64.exe"
"Hash"="gkalOpSfHNg="
```

Apparently, there's a thing called OpenWith.exe, which gets considered first in the OpenWithList. And, the "Default Apps" has its own list of associations - probably the one stored in UserChoice...

Seems a tad convoluted, but at least now it works for me :-)

But wait, that's not all.
There is one other thing I was wrong about.

I took that offending .IMG file, and tried dissecting it a little, under Linux (= under sanitary conditions). The "file" tool in Linux told me, that my suspicious .IMG file was really a UDF filesystem image. I know what the UDF is. So I mounted that in Linux to a temporary location. Which succeeded. Inside, there was something like invoice,jpg.exe . BTW, written in something.NET, by the human-readable contents. Oh yeah - must be some really mighty malware. I did not try to execute that, just submitted the sample to Microsoft (via Defender's submission form), in case they were interested.

What this means:
The .IMG file itself was probably harmless.
What Explorer did, it probably "loop-"mounted the image file = possibly assigned the volume a drive letter, and probably did not pop up an Explorer window showing its root directory. Thus, neither the user, nor me, have noticed the drive letter appearing.
Yet, while/because the image file was mounted, it was in use, by the system. As duly reported when we tried to delete it. Unsurprisingly, after a restart (into the safe mode), the image file was no longer mounted, and thus available for deletion.
The user has not in fact found the forged .JPG file (a covert EXE), and did not try to run it. No harm was probably done.
The .IMG file itself, or its "processing" by File Explorer, probably does not lead to malicious code execution (buffer overflow style or something).

The .IMG is probably just a benign container/wrapper, "hopefully" opaque for e-mail antivirus/antimalware tools, used by the malware authors to smuggle the attack binary .EXE to the unsuspecting user. I've seen .ISO used this way, and possibly some less common archive formats (RAR, ARJ). Though some past versions of some archivers used to be susceptible to direct attacks too.

Comment: Looking back, my question was somewhat mis-informed / under-educated, and I now have a fairly detailed solution/explanation, including a bit of a tangent. I have decided not to pollute my original question with edits and updates, turning it into an answer or some such. Instead, I've added my own answer - while keeping Keith's answer as the accepted answer, because as far as I'm concerned, the accolades go to him.